# Background color of QComboBox does not change properly on windows 7

Tags: qt, colors, combobox, background

I am using QT (latest-5.6.0 msvc 64-bit) and want the comboBox to be displayed as white but it does not seem display correctly on win 7.

I have tried one or more combinations of the following:

```
QPalette p = ui.comboBox->palette();
    p.setColor(QPalette::Active, QPalette::Button, Qt::white);
    p.setColor(QPalette::Inactive, QPalette::Button, Qt::white);
    p.setColor(QPalette::Active, QPalette::Background, Qt::white);
    p.setColor(QPalette::Active, QPalette::Base, Qt::white);
    p.setColor(QPalette::Inactive, QPalette::Background, Qt::white);
    p.setColor(QPalette::Inactive, QPalette::Base, Qt::white);
    p.setColor(ui.comboBox->backgroundRole(), Qt::white);
    ui.comboBox->setPalette(p)
```

But none of them do change the display at least on win 7. I have also tried this:

```
ui.comboBox->setStyleSheet("QComboBox { background-color: white; }");
```

But the display became this: 
[image]

Although it is white the down pointer has a grey box around it. I want it more like this: [image]

Edit: I have tried this:

```
ui.comboBox->setStyleSheet("QComboBox { background-color: white; } QComboBox::drop-down { background-color: white; }");
```

but down arrow is not shown. How to change color while still showing the arrow?

Any solutions, suggestions, or ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well currently, I found a solution. while it may not be the best, works which is to add a custom down arrow image (black arrow on a white background) and use it with stylesheet as follows:

```
    ui.comboBox->setStyleSheet("
QComboBox { background-color: white; } 
QComboBox::drop-down { image:url(:/Stock_Purchase_Simulator/Resources/arrow.png); }");
```